Partner user can see Internal User's Case Record in Partner Community even it's private record
It's all about Sharing Record on Case
First of all, OWD for Case is Private (Internal/External Both) which means they can view only their own case record.
There are 2 Partner user under same account, and one of them can view Internal User's case record in Partner community.
I looked through what's different between these 2 Partner user, and one of them who can see the internal user's case record has Field Service Permission (all from FSL Package).
But I checked all permission from the package and also Object permission but there was no access for Case object ..
And after Case is Inserted , we have trigger to create Work Order and Service Appointment Object . These are Standard Object also.
And the Partner User can't see those 2 Records.
Only can see Case Record.
And next i was looking for Apex Sharing Rule. I queried "CaseShare" Object for the Partner User who can see the case, but there's no UserOrGroupId with that partner User,
which means There's no Case Sharing Rule made.
And next There's no Connection with that Case Contact Record (I'm talking about  "Grant site users access to related cases" <- this setting) no
And next 2 partner user have same Profile
and same Role and same hierarchy Level. and there's no problem that 2 users can see their own case record and work Order and Service Appointment record.
The most suspicious thing for me is FSL Permission giving access to view the other's record to Partner User.But it's not that the Partner user who can see the internal's case record can see all case records.
I don't know what i have to check more.. please help me even it's small thing
Thank you
